# Wordpress visual editor not displaying bullet points

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having a problem with my blog, Ive made a page, wrote all the content on the html side of the editor, listed some items and published it, the bullet points show up and all is fine but when i switch into visual editor, I can still see the bullet points but if i click update then or add to the list or amend it, the bullet points themselves disappear, but the listed items keep their css styles ( abit of bottom padding ), any help onto how to get them to appear when using visual editor?

this is my css for the list items

```
 ol, ul {
list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
li { 
  padding-bottom:5px;
   }
```

I have list-style:none because its hiding header and footer links which are listed.
I've changed list-style to circle and list-style-position ect and the header and footer bullets show up again but nothing happens to the "bulleted" list item on my page.

anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
list-style:none;
```

Kinda self explanatory. Remove it and the bullet points will appear again.

Comment: That doesnt work, ive got rid of it, and the header and footer listed items show up, but still the "bullets" on my page dont. any ideas?

Comment: Well, using chrome's inspect element (or other browser's, but I am 100% sure chrome has it cause I use it) feature, have a look at what css properties these elements have. You may see that `list-style:none;` is still on and you are trying to change it in the wrong place.

Comment: it says li: padding 5px and inherited from ul list-style: none; it showed up when i put <li> infront of the items on the html side, but when i switched to visual editor, it then disappeared

Comment: Just as I guessed somewhere it is still `list-style:none;` You have to find why it has it on. Must be declared or inherited somewhere.